# Solve using Quadratic Formula Question, What went wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Okay the question is to solve using quadratic formula and the question is $10r^2-6=0$ and after using the $-b \pm \frac{\sqrt{ b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ I got $-0 \pm \frac{\sqrt{240}}{20}$...and I don't know where to go after that...i thought about taking square root but than i get $15$ something $20$??

Comment: Well, is there not a simpler way to solve the question?
$10r^2=6$...

Comment: As @Feyre said, it is simple solution. $r=\pm \sqrt{\frac 35}$

Comment: Just write out the prime factorization of $240$. You will see that it can be factored as $16\times 15$

Answer (score 2):

If you're required to use quadratic formula, you just need to simplify:

$\pm \frac{\sqrt{240}}{20} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{240}}{\sqrt{400}} =\pm \sqrt{\frac{240}{400}} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$

Otherwise, as Feyre pointed out, there's no reason to use the quadratic formula and you can just solve it directly

Comment: yea i had to use quadratic formula....thanks a lot for the answer but the answer in the answer sheet is ± square root of 15 divided by 5, but the 5 is not inside the square root...15 is the only one inside it....and also it im sorry but i had a error in the question...

Comment: @MATHASKER: $\frac{\sqrt{15}}5 = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{\sqrt{25}} = \sqrt{\frac{15}{25}} = \sqrt{\frac 35}$

Comment: Most math classes will require reductions of all radicals, fractions, and rationalized denominators. So the reduction you'd see would be: $\frac {\sqrt{240}}{20} = \frac {\sqrt{16*15}}{20} = \frac {4 \sqrt{15}} {4*5} =  \frac {\sqrt{15}}{5}$.